# Trouble sending PHP headers?

Tags: php, curl, header, http-headers

so, quick question everyone... I have a PHP file that generates an edited image. The file looks like the following. It grabs an image from the server and crops it under certain specifications.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$src = getcwd()."/".$_GET["img"].".jpg";
$screenw = $_GET["sw"];
$screenh = $_GET["sh"];


$jpeg_quality = 100;

$w = $screenw;
$h = 428;

$targ_w = $w;
$targ_h = $h;

$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor($targ_w, $targ_h);

$x = 1000 - floor($screenw / 2);
$y = 1000 - floor(428 / 2);

imagecopyresampled($dst_r, $img_r, 0, 0, $x, $y, $targ_w, $targ_h, $w, $h);

imagejpeg($dst_r, null, 100);
exit;
?>
```

The file runs fine on my local MAMP server. However, when I upload it to 000webhost, I immediately get a

> The image image1 cannot be displayed because it contains errors

message. And, after some testing, I deemed my header was the cause of it. If I curl it, the results for the live site are:

```
Date: Mon, 11 Nov 2013 06:47:40 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Connection: close
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

and localhost:

```
Date: Mon, 11 Nov 2013 06:52:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 PHP/5.4.10
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.10
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

I see that the connection closes before the header is sent on the live site, thus throwing the error... why is this happening? Is it a problem with my code? Can this be resolved in PHP? Please let me know. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Show us your complete image delivery code.

Comment: I added the rest of the code just now as a post edit

Comment: Try `ob_end_clean()` before you send the header and the content. `error_reporting(E_ALL);` does not report any errors I think?

Answer (score 0):

I realized this is a problem with 000webhost.. not only do they add tracking code to the end of your page, but they also send a newline to the top of the file. This was sending a header before the other header could be sent, so adding this to an htaccess file corrected the problem:

```
php_value auto_append_file none
php_value auto_prepend_file none
```

Thanks anyway though guys.